# PHP property of another class

Tags: php

I'm not 100% sure, but is this a correct way of defining a property:

```
class Product {
    public $id;
    public $name;
}

class LineItem {
    public Product $product; //<------ this property
    public $qty;
}
```

Or, is it best to leave it as `$product` with no type identifier?

Comment: You can't have type identifiers in PHP at all. Just `$product` is the only legal way to declare the property.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks, you might as well put as an answer :) and i'll accept

Comment: RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: It's worth noting that you can have type *hints* in function definitions, e.g. `public function test(Product $product)`. Note my usage of the word *hints*.

Comment: @No1_Melman: I see there's already another answer, so accept that one :)

Comment: @Marty see I'm getting downvotes, but this is where I got the confusion!! In functions you can, but not for classes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Jon already suggested in the comments. PHP doesn't indeed not support type identifiers. The best approach for this (or at least as I'd do it). Would be to just define `$product` and then create the constructor which instantiates a new Product object in that class variable. Or just pass in the object when you need it with a getter / setter method in the LineItem class.

**edit:** It does differ from the situation (you didn't gave a situation, so I tried to guess it and give an example).

Constructor:

```
public function __construct($product = new Product()) {
    $this->product = $product;
}
```

Getter / setter work like same way:

```
public function getProduct() {

    return $this->product;
}

//In arguments you're able to make sure it is of a class Product if I'm correct.
public function setProduct(Product $product) {

    $this->product = $product;

    //You might do a return of $this, dependent on your logic of course.
    return $this;
}
```

**edit:** Added the below code for future users who might benefit of it.
In regular PHP file you can do for example the following:

```
$product = new Product();
//Set some price, description or something in your product...

//Pass product with constructor.
$lineItem = new LineItem($product);

//Get the product of the lineItem...
$product = $lineItem->getProduct();

//Set a product if constructor hasn't been used...
$lineItem->setProduct($product);
```

Comment: No this is fine, it's just the situation of like creating a class

Answer (score 3):

Product should be defined this way:

```
public $product;
```

and create it as:

```
$product = new Product();
```

Comment: I will accept in 11mins :) according to stackoverflow

Comment: `$this->product = new Product()` is correct instead.

Answer (score 1):

As Jon said, you can't have type identifiers in PHP.

You *could* do something like this and use the `instanceof` operator:

```
class LineItem {
      protected $_product;
      //...

      public function setProduct($p) {
          if($p instanceof Product) {
              $this->_product = $p;
          } else {
              throw new Exception("...");
          }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Type Hinting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) on `__construct()`:

```
class Product {
    public $id;
    public $name;
}

class LineItem {
    public function __construct(Product $product) {
        $this->product = $product;
    }
    public $qty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set it in a constructor

```
class Product {
    public $id;
    public $name;
}

class LineItem {
    public $product; 
    public $qty;

    function __construct(){
        $this->product = new Product();
    }  
}
```